# "Package has no %description:" when packaging an rpm

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am packaging a very simple rpm of a redmine plugin, for internal use, and I am stuck with a "Package has no %description:" error.

The .spec has a description and I couldn't find anything relevant on the inet. Here goes my .spec:

```
codeName:           redmine_knowledgebase
Version:        2.2.1
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Redmine plugin to add knowledgbase functionality
Group:          redmine-plugins
License:        MIT
URL:            https://github.com/alexbevi/redmine_knowledgebase
Source0:        redmine_knowledgebase.tar.gz
BuildRoot:      %(mktemp -ud %{tmp/%{name}-%{version}-%{release})
BuildRequires:
Requires:       redmine, ruby, rubygems

%description
Redmine plugin to add knowledgbase functionality
%prep
%setup -q -n redmine_knowledgebase

%build

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
install -m 0755 / /var/www/redmine/plugins/
bundle install
rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=redmine_knowledgebase

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%files
%defattr(-,apache,apache,-)
/var/www/redmine/plugins/*
%post
echo " "
echo "This will display after rpm installs the package!"
echo "If the plugin does not work, check the permissions ans ownership of the newly created ../redmine/plugins/redmine_knowledgebase"
```

rpmlint gives me the following errors:

```
rpmlint ../SPECS/redmine_knowledgebase.spec 
../SPECS/redmine_knowledgebase.spec:5: W: non-standard-group redmine-plugins
../SPECS/redmine_knowledgebase.spec: E: specfile-error error: Package has no %description: redmine_knowledgebase
../SPECS/redmine_knowledgebase.spec: E: specfile-error error: query of specfile ../SPECS/redmine_knowledgebase.spec failed, can't parse
0 packages and 1 specfiles checked; 2 errors, 1 warnings
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a newline before `%prep`?

Comment: Yes. I have tried to add multiple newlines, re-write that section from scratch but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently "Package has no %description" pops up when an unidentified error occurs.
I solved this by formatting better the .spec:
-I have given a path to source0
-I have provided a BuildRequired package (anything will do, I put gcc in there)
-I have fixed indentation to use only tabs

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it's because your braces are not balanced?

```
BuildRoot:      %(mktemp -ud %{tmp/%{name}-%{version}-%{release})
```

Balanced:

```
BuildRoot:      %(mktemp -ud %{tmp}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release})
```